# How to import a JSON file into MATLAB programatically?

Tags: json, matlab, twitter, import

I am trying to load my data from a JSON file into MATLAB that is delimited with `,`.
The format of my data is as follows:

```
{"created_at": "Mon Oct 27 20:35:47 +0000 2014", "tweet": "Silver Finished Up, Gold, Copper, Crude Oil, Nat Gas Down - Live Trading News http://t.co/jNLTUIgHwA", "id": 526834668759285761, "sentiment": "negative"}

{"created_at": "Mon Oct 27 20:36:21 +0000 2014", "tweet": "Gold, Silver slips on lacklustre demand- The Economic Times http://t.co/Jd5Tn9ctfX", "id": 526834810300289024, "sentiment": "negative"}
```

How would I do so?

Comment: Are you saying you're looking for a JSON parser for MATLAB? I bet Google would give you a quicker response. Also, ‘JSON file [...] that is delimited with `,`’, what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: By delimited I mean I want each variable (created at, tweet, etc) to be separated into separate columns

Comment: filename = 'myfile01.txt';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);

Comment: this works but it stores only in one column

Comment: So you mean you want to parse the JSON... as JSON?

Comment: I want to load data from a JSON file into an array in matlab

Comment: That information should have gone into the question from the beginning.

Comment: Oh, and the example ‘JSON’ isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Oh ok, what would be the best approach?

Comment: reformat the json file and then try to re-run the command in matlab

Answer (score 5):

As of version 2016b, Matlab has integrated json support.

See:
**https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html**

In short, you do:

```
jsonData = jsondecode(fileread('file.json'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use jsonLab](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files-in-matlab-octave)

One line to read:

```
 tweet_info = loadjson('~/Desktop/test.json')
```

Here's what's stored in tweet_info{1}

```
   created_at: 'Mon Oct 27 20:35:47 +0000 2014'
     tweet: 'Silver Finished Up, Gold, Copper, Crude Oil, Nat Gas Down - Live Trading News      http://t.co/jNLTUIgHwA'
        id: 5.2683e+17
 sentiment: 'negative'
```

Here's what stored in the test.json file

> {"created_at": "Mon Oct 27 20:35:47 +0000 2014", "tweet": "Silver Finished Up, Gold, Copper, Crude Oil, Nat Gas Down - Live Trading News http://t.co/jNLTUIgHwA", "id": 526834668759285761, "sentiment": "negative"}
>
> {"created_at": "Mon Oct 27 20:36:21 +0000 2014", "tweet": "Gold, Silver slips on lacklustre demand- The Economic Times http://t.co/Jd5Tn9ctfX", "id": 526834810300289024, "sentiment": "negative"}

Comment: when calling the function What parameters must i specify ?

Comment: what does varargin refer to ?

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'varargin2struct'.

Error in loadjson (line 61)
opt=varargin2struct(varargin{:});

Comment: varargin allows you to have variable input arguments. I'm attaching the file I used so you can check if it's your file or something else...

Comment: yh thats fine but what parameter should i pass as varargin

Comment: You should use the function call I provided:  tweet_info = loadjson(FILE_NAME_WITH_PATH). THere should be no need for additional arguments to the function.